# Count the Ones from 1 to 99,999,999

Tags: c#

I am seeking an algorithm that can simply count how many 1's are there from 1 to 99,999,999 as fast as possible

There are many ways but I need the fastest.

Actually the right number is 80000000

My try in c#:

```
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
int counter = 0;

sw.Start();
for (int i = 1; i <= 99999999; i++)
{
  int num = i;
  while (num > 0)
  {

      if (num % 10==1)
        {
            counter++;
        }

      num = num / 10;
  }
}

sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("1 is counted {0} times and prog time is {1}", counter, sw.Elapsed.ToString());
```

i don't know the math formula to get it without any loop as i think it will be the fastest way !!

Comment: Hint: You don't really need a loop. You could solve this with just a little bit of math.

Comment: what do you mean, "1's". how many numbers contain a `1` digit (`111` contains a one, so it counts for `1`), or literally how many `1` show up in all of the numbers? e.g. `11` counts for 2?

Comment: then just `return 80000000` it's the fastest way

Comment: smells like homework

Comment: agree with @p.s.w.g, a loop here is the most brutish of force, especially considering the repeated use of `%`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g: yeah, that sounds right although I'm trying to figure it out now....grrrrr must do real work!

Comment: `smells like homework and sounds like OP missed a few days in class`

Comment: This is literally just `100,000,000 * 8 / 10`

Comment: @Rotem It's also literally 40000000 * 2, but that doesn't help the OP. The important thing is how you arrived at that equation.

Comment: @itsme86 Number of total digits in the range, divided by 10, because the chances of it being a 1 are 1/10.

Comment: @itsme86 Of course this only works for numbers which are powers of 10.

Comment: @Rotem: The correct formula for the number of ones that appear in the numbers less than 10^n is n times 10^(n-1). In your case n is 8.  But I agree with the rest of the commenters; the fastest way to compute that number is simply to return it.

Answer (score 1):

actually i managed to do it without any loops so that's considered the fastest way and i am gonna share it for knowlagde

```
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        int counter = 0;
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        int n=8;

        counter =(int) (n * Math.Pow(10, n - 1));
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("1 is counted {0} times and prog time is {1}", counter, sw.Elapsed.ToString());
```